# Express and async/await: shall I wrap the lot with try/catch?

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, try-catch

I have the following code:

```
app.post('/routes/passwordReset/:userId', async (req, res, next) => {
  var userId = req.params.userId

  let record = (await vars.connection.queryP('SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = ?', userId))[0]

  if (!record) {
    res.status(404).send('')
    return
  }

  // Calculate token and expiry, update database
  var token = require('crypto').randomBytes(48).toString('base64').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '').substr(0, 28)
  var now = new Date()
  var inOneHour = new Date(now.getTime() + (1 * 1000 * 60 * 60))
  await vars.connection.queryP('UPDATE contacts SET recoverToken = ?, recoverTokenExpiry = ? WHERE id = ?', [ token, inOneHour, userId ])
  res.status(200).send('')
})
```

If I create an artificial error (e.g. the field for `recoverTokenExpiry` is artificially too short) I end up with:

> [[12:19:55.649]] [ERROR] (node:11919)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 4): Error: ER_DATA_TOO_LONG: Data too long for column
>   'recoverToken' at row 1

I somehow thought that Express would have try/catch around middleware and called `next(err)` if an error was thrown. Maybe not so?

So, should I wrap each route with try/catch(e), doing next(e) if there is an error?

Comment: please refer here for middleware try/catch https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html something like 
`app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
});`

Comment: The error middleware doesn't get called as the error isn't gettint caught...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Express does not do anything for you. It is very bare bones.

You have two options:

1. Wrap everything in a `try-catch`
2. Write your own error handling middleware as shown in the docs [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

Calling `next()` will pass the `req` and `res` to the next middleware in the stack.

Calling `next(err)`, in other giving it an `Exception` object, will call any error middleware in the stack.

---

Define your error handlers in its own file:

```
// error-middleware.js

/**
 * Handler to catch `async` operation errors.
 * Reduces having to write `try-catch` all the time.
 */
exports.catchErrors = action => (req, res, next) => action(req, res).catch(next)

/**
 * Show useful information to client in development.
 */
exports.devErrorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  err.stack = err.stack || ''
  const status = err.status || 500
  const error = { message: err.message }
  res.status(status)
  res.json({ status, error })
}
```

Then move your password reset logic out of `app.post` and into its own dedicated function:

```
// password-controller.js

exports.resetPassword = async (req, res) => {
  // do work
  // ...
}
```

This makes it easier to write unit tests for and a clear separation of concerns.

Next create your password reset route(s):

```
// password-reset-routes.js

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const passwordController = require('./password-controller')
const { catchErrors } = require('./error-middleware')

router.post('/routes/passwordReset/:userId', catchErrors(passwordController.resetPassword))

module.exports = router
```

Notice that the controller defined above is imported and used here. In addition you see that the controller action `resetPassword` is wrapped with `catchErrors`. This avoids having to write `try-catch` all the time and any errors will be caught by the `catchErrors` middleware.

Finally, wire it all up in your main `app.js` file:

```
// app.js

const express = require('express')
const { devErrorHandler } = require('./error-middleware')
const passwordResetRoutes = require('./password-reset-routes.js')
const app = express()

app.use(devErrorHandler)
app.use(passwordResetRoutes)

module.exports = app
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand "option 2": I already have error handling middleware in place. However, it doesn't get called unless I have try-catch there. So... I assume I would have to have both (1) and (2), so that I do `try { ... } catch (e) { next(err) }` right?

Comment: You _can_ do that or wrap the function in a `catch` since `async` functions always return a `Promise`. See updated answer with example.

Comment: Could you add the `async` declaration to `exports.catchErrors = action => (req, res, next) => action(req, res).catch(next)
`. Would it catch async errors to then?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you're using await keyword, it means the execution flow isn't asynchronous anymore, that's why it fails and yes, you must use try-catch block every time. To avoid this, you can instead follow the asynchronous flow and use then() and catch() respectively, so you can do something like:

```
...
.then((status)=>{
  res.status(200).send('')
})
.catch((err)=>{
  next(err);
});
...
```

Comment: I understand, but promises are an (important) ES standard, I don't know if it's possible to use them without `then()` and `catch` methods. You could try something else like Observables (not an ES standard yet), or just stop using JS/Node, which in my opinion is not an option

Answer (score 0):

As others have responded, since you are using await, you can handle the promise rejection as

```
let record = await vars.connection.queryP('SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = ?', userId))[0].then(function () {
     console.log("Promise Resolved");
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log("Promise rejected")
})
```